# How to Resolve View Model with Autofac having just Type of the view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, types, datacontext

In application with Autofac container and having registered VM I need to assign DataContext in a situation, where i have just view models Type.

MainViewModel calls **NavigationService**:

`await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<UpdateViewModel>();`

And in my service class, how to do from this (**this works fine**):

```
private async Task InternalNavigateToAsync(Type viewModelType, object parameter)
        {
            var bootStrapper = new BootStrapper();
            var container = bootStrapper.BootStrap();

            Window window = CreateWindow(viewModelType, parameter);
            //this works fine
            if (viewModelType.Name == "MainViewModel")
            {
                window.DataContext = container.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
            }
            if (viewModelType.Name == "UpdateViewModel")
            {
                window.DataContext = container.Resolve<UpdateViewModel>();
            }
            window.Show();
        }
```

this (**is not working**):

```
private async Task InternalNavigateToAsync(Type viewModelType, object parameter)
        {
            var bootStrapper = new BootStrapper();
            var container = bootStrapper.BootStrap();

            Window window = CreateWindow(viewModelType, parameter);
            //but how to do this?
            window.DataContext = container.Resolve<viewModelType>();

            window.Show();
        }
```

And it gives me an error:

> 'viewModelType' is a variable but is used like a type

Comment: pass the type as argument `window.DataContext = container.Resolve(viewModelType);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the type as argument to `Resolve(Type serviceType)`

```
window.DataContext = container.Resolve(viewModelType);
```

instead of trying to use it as a generic argument

Comment: Ok, I spent last 5 hours trying to deal with this. And it was so simple. Thank you!